# JavaScript Callback Use-case

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I am not very familiar with `callback()` functions. I am looking for an explanation and an example of what a proper use case might be. *In my example below, how can I utilize a callback and also, should I?*

Here I have two functions:

```
addShape = function () {
      ExampleService.createShape(function () {  //ajax
         shapeMade = true;
         //anything else etc.......
      });
}

deleteShape = function () {
      ExampleService.removeShape(function () {  //ajax
         shapeMade = false;
         //anything else etc.......
      });
}
```

The third function (focus of my question)

```
resetShape = function () {
      deleteShape();
      addShape();
      console.log('example');
}
```

When I call the `resetShape()` function, the `example` gets logged to the console before both `deleteShape()` and `addShape()` have finished.

Would this be a situation to use a `callback()`? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: No. First of all javascript's lifetime ends as soon as you reload/leave the page. The only reason you can work with the same data is because you've specifically programmed it to. Callbacks are used in order to control the logic when a specific (usually asynchronous) function has done something. If you know about AJAX, it's one big use case for using callbacks, as you don't get the response right away.

Comment: @h2ooooooo that is incorrect, they are NOT JUST USED for getting data back. They are used when you need to do something after an asynchronous operation occurred.

Comment: @epascarello You're right - my formulation of that was way wrong (and has been changed!). :-)

Comment: sorry.. I just clarified my post. I am making ajax requests.

Comment: @captainrad Why are you using `window.location.reload` unless you want your entire page to reload?

Comment: @h2ooooooo just using it as an example, I'll edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks are used for asynchronous functions.  In this case, since you have multiple async function to wait for, you probably want to use a [`Promise`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), and `Promise.all` to execute the callback when all async operations are complete:

```
resetShape = function () {
  Promise.all([ deleteShape(), addShape() ]).then( function() {
      console.log('example');
  });
}
```

Note that, for this to work, your functions "deleteShape" and "addShape" have to return the promise object:

```
addShape = function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      ExampleService.createShape(function () {
          shapeMade = true;
          resolve();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Callbacks are often used for asynchronous functions, but that's not the only reason why you might have a function that takes another function.

Comment: @MattBurland for sure.  But "callback" implies an asyc operation, doesn't it?  In other words, "callback" is just shorthand for "asynchronous callback".

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that it does. A callback is any function that another function might "callback" whether it's asynchronous or not. Event handlers are an example of a callback, but they are not asynchronous. `Array.forEach` also takes a callback, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) page even calls it `callback` and it most certainly isn't asynchronous. This is a functional programming concept not an exclusively asynchronous concept.

Answer (score 1):

A callback is used mainly for two reasons, to give another object or function a way to tell us something we were waiting for has completed (or changed) or a way to get something from us when they require it.

1. First case: imagine a function that makes an asynchronous request to
   a server. We don't know how much time it'll take to complete, so we
   give the requester a way to tell us it's done:

   ```
   getDataFromServer('foo.php', callback); //callback will be called when the request 
                                       //is done. We can do something else meanwhile.
   ```
2. Second case. I could create and object that, when needed, will ask
   for more data (ie, getting more rows to append to a table when we
   scroll down)

   ```
   var tableBuilder = new TableBuilder(container, dataGetterCallback);
   ```

dataGetterCallback will be called whenever TableBuilder needs more rows. It'll have the logic to give it to them (maybe by receiving a parameter that tells it in which index to start).

Hope this gives you an idea.